# PHP: changing code if domain is testing environment

Tags: php, server, digital-ocean

I have 2 droplets on digitalocean.
Droplet 1: Live Environment.
Droplet 2: Test Environment.

I frequently take a snapshot of a given droplet and rebuild the other droplet with that image (to make sure both servers are setup the same way). Then I'll FTP into the test server and make appropriate changes to lock the domain down.

**The Problem:** I need to change some php code every time I do this, example changing an api endpoint to it's testing counter part. etc.

I've been thinking I could write some code that will automatically change to test/live based off the domain..

Is this bad? I'm afraid if I have domain dependent code the website could take a performance hit simply because it has to check every time it is run.

Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: Look into the concept of "environment variables".

Comment: That sounds like an excellent solution. Another thing is, is it okay to have 1 ssl cert that includes both domains. It would be on both servers but only 1 domain would be used at a given time

Comment: That depends a bit on you. If you use a multi-domain certificate that has `www.example.com` and `super-secret-subdomain.example.com`, someone looking at the certificate can find that secret subdomain. If you don't care about someone knowing your staging/testing site's domain (or if it's protected in some other way), feel free. Otherwise, you may want two separate certs (or a wildcard, which gives less away).

Comment: Is it on a static IP? You could limit based on the server IP.

Comment: @B3none that is one way of doing it however I think it would be better to do it bases of the domain, in case you have multiple server around the globe with a load balancer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as ceejayoz said, you need to implement some form of environment variables. One way would be having some form of configuration file that stored the values. You could name the file based on the server and include it when necessary.

But really, just checking what server you're on won't have any real negligible affect as it'd be done once per script execution (and is just a string compare).